# How do I apply a flag to a library in SCons?

Tags: build, linker, scons

I need to execute a build command similar to:

```
g++ -Wl,-rpath=../libs source.o -static -Wl,-Bdynamic -ldynlib -Wl,-Bstatic -lstaticlib
```

My current (wrong) SConscript links in dynlib with this line:

```
env.AppendUnique(LINKFLAGS=['-Wl,-Bdynamic', '-ldynlib']);
```

However when I run scons, I get this:

```
g++ -Wl,-rpath=../libs -static -Wl,-Bdynamic -ldynlib source.o -Wl,-Bstatic -lstaticlib
```

Because source.o is after dynlib, it can't find dynlib, and this causes link errors. The solution (verified manually) is to move source.o before dynlib, which is a vendor-provided library.

Ideally I'd add dynlib to LIBS but SCons does not appear to support flags there.

What workaround can I use to get SCons to generate the correct build line?

Comment: Please show your full SConscript, such that we can see where the flags "`-Wl,-Bstatic -lstaticlib`" are coming from. Wouldn't you be able to specify the "`-ldynlib`" at the same place where the "`-lstatic`" is given? That should resolve your issue nicely... If this doesn't work for some reason, please also show how you call *SCons* and post the full verbatim output.

Comment: You raise a good point, which led me to the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Literal turned out to be the solution. For whatever reason, SCons doesn't prepend '-l' to my flags now.

```
    env['FORCEDYNAMIC'] = env.Literal('-Wl,-Bdynamic')
    env.PrependUnique(LIBS = [['${FORCEDYNAMIC}', 'dynlib']])
```